# When assembly of atoms is influenced by EM wave only few of them get excited not all? Why?

Tags: laser

In laser when assembly of atoms is influenced by em wave, only few of the atoms get excited not all? why it happens

Comment: Why, when bowling, don't you get a strike every time?

Answer (score 0):

A laser is a device that emits light through a process of optical amplification based on stimulated emission of EM radiation.

Lasers emit light coherently. There are two types of coherence:

1. spatial, light emitted by a laser is collimated, can get focused on a tight spot.
2. temporal coherence, light has a very narrow spectrum

Now when a laser is used to influence a material, for example to excite atoms in the material, what they do is they focus the laser on a certain part of the material.

There are basically a few reasons why not all atoms get excited by the laserlight:

1. photons from the laser do not physically interact with certain atoms, just because laser light is spatially coherent, focused on a tight spot on the material
2. photons from the laser do not excite some atoms in the material, just because the photons are temporally coherent, meaning the laser emits a single color of light, and that means a certain wavelength of photons, and that does not match the energy level needed from the photons to excite the specific atoms
3. we have to accept that our universe is Quantum Mechanical, and it is all about probabilities. Even if the laserlight is focused spatially at a certain group of atoms, and even if the energy level of the photons does match the energy level needed to excite the specific atoms, some atoms might not get excited
4. The same is true if you try to excite a single atom with a laser. There is a certain probability as per QM that the atom will be excited but this is less then 100%.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser